# Subring of a ring is an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am a little bit confused with this question while reading the ring theory.

'If a subring of a ring is an integral domain, does it imply the Ring is also an integral domain?'
I know this fact that if a ring is an integral domain, is its subring also an integral domain.

Can anyone please give some hints? Thank you.

Comment: If $K$ is a field, the ring $K[x]/(x^2)$ has a subring isomorphic to $K$.

Comment: Let $R$ be an integral domain. Then it is also a subring of $R\oplus R$, which is not an integral domain.

Answer (score 2):

Take for instance $M_2(\mathbb R)$. The scalar matrices are a subring which is an integral domain (it is in fact a field). But $M_2(\mathbb R)$ is definitely not an integral domain.

The idea is that even if you know that the ring 'behaves nicely' on a subset, there is definitely no reason for it to act nicely everywhere.